# Reusing the same let bindings

Tags: clojure, let

I'm refactoring my test suite for a clojure application and am trying to figure out if there is a way to save let bindings for reuse to minimize copied code, as many tests require the similar setup but interfere with each other and require their own deftest. Ideally, I would like it to work a little like this:

```
(def let-bindings [bind1 val1 bind2 val2 bind3 val3])

(deftest test-1
  (testing "my test"
    (let (conj let-bindings [bind4 val4])
      ...)))

(deftest test-2
  (testing "my second test"
    (let (conj let-bindings [bind5 val5])
      ...)))
```

For added clarification, I need val1 and val2 to be evaluated in the test, not when defining the let bindings, as the calls affect the test database in a way that needs to be reset after each test. Does this mean I need a macro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`let` is a special form so trying to metaprogram it without doing it in a macro won't  work. Perhaps you should just define the common bindings instead:

```
(def bind1 val1) 
(def bind2 val2) 
(def bind3 val3)

(deftest test-1
  (testing "my test"
    (let [bind4 val4]
      ;; here bind1...bind4 would be available
      ...)))

...
```

**EDIT**

Here is how I imagine you could do it with a macro:

```
;; notice that the let will be recreated each time so if
;; val1 ... are computational hard consider caching. 
(defmacro elet [ bindings & body ] 
  `(let [bind1 val1 bind2 val2 bind3 val3 ~@bindings] 
     ~@body))

(deftest test-1
  (testing "my test"
    (elet [bind4 val4]
      ;; here bind1...bind4 would be available
      ...)))

...
```

Comment: This is what I am currently doing and it's serviceable but quite clunky (many groups of tests have around 10 common bindings in a let). Out of curiosity, how would I do this with a macro? It's not something I really have experience with.

Comment: @user1231120 I'm not really a Clojure expert but I believe my edit will work.

Comment: Thank you! I'm just learning myself and have never worked with macros.

Answer (score 0):

To do this without macros you could go this way:

```
(def m {:a 1 :b 2})

(deftest foo []
  (println (m :a)))

(foo)
;; prints 1

(let [m (assoc m :c 3)]
  (deftest bar
    (println (m :c))))

(bar)
;; prints 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use fixtures to redefine dynamic bindings across tests and access the values within deftest. Fixtures can be defined once for all or each deftest.

```
(def ^:dynamic m)

(defn once-fixture
  [tests]
  (binding [m {:a 1 :b 2}]
    (tests)))

(use-fixtures :once once-fixture)

(deftest testing-binding
  (is (= (:a m) 1)
    "Dynamic binding is working"))
```